# Python SyntaxError: invalid syntax for "elif len(org) >= 1:"

Tags: python, syntax-error

When importing the following function to the Ipython 1.1 interpreter a SyntaxError is raised telling me that "elif len(org) >= 1:" is invalid syntax. My immediate thought is that my spacing should be incorrect but that does not appear to be the case.

If we walk through this function from the initial for loop on line 3, the error is raised on the third set of if/elif statements.

Given that this is a rather unpythonic function it may be best to break this up into several smaller functions. That should resolve the SyntaxError.

Would you agree that breaking this function into smaller functions is the best way to resolve this error? Do you know why the error was raised when the spacing and syntax appears, at least to me, to be correct?

Thank you for your time!

```
def get_it(test_this):
    find_full_word = []
    for token in st.tag(test_this.split()):
        name = []
        org = []
        loc = []
        if len(token) == 2:
            x,y = token
            if y == 'PERSON':  
                name.append(x)
            elif y == 'ORGANIZATION':
                org.append(x)
            elif y == 'LOCATION':
                loc.append(x)
            elif y == 'O':
                if len(name) >= 1:
                    n_term = ""
                    for n_item in name:
                        if len(n_term) > 0:
                            n_term = n_term + " " + n_item
                        else:
                            n_term = n_item
                    while len(name) > 0:
                        name.pop()
                    find_full_word.append((n_term, "PERSON")
              ### error is raised here ####
                elif len(org) >= 1:
              # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
                    o_term = ""
                    for o_item in org:
                        if len(o_term) > 0:
                            o_term = o_term + " " + o_item
                        else:
                            o_term = o_item
                    while len(org) > 0:
                        org.pop()
                    find_full_word.append(o_term,"ORGANIZATION")
                elif len(loc) >= 1:
                    l_term = ""
                    for l_item in loc:
                        if len(l_term) > 0:
                            l_term = l_term + " " + l_item
                        else:
                            l_term = l_item
                    while len(loc) > 0:
                        loc.pop()
                    find_full_word.append(l_term, "LOCATION")
        if len(name) == 1:
            find_full_word.append(name)
        elif len(org) == 1:
            find_full_word.append(org)
        elif len(loc) == 1:
            find_full_word.append(loc)
        else:
            raise UserWarning("No PERSON, ORGANIZATION, LOCATION was found")
    return find_full_word
```

Comment: In this case the spacing appears to be correct – but it’s damn hard to see! Don’t use that many levels of indentation, they make the code extremely hard to read. [Flatten your indentation level.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html)

Comment: @alko Actually if you copy&paste the code into an editor (which supports vertical selection) you can verify that the spacing is correct.

Comment: put `y == 'O'` branch into a separate function, to make it easier to read.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think the more pressing problem is that the code is long and repetitive. It's also harder to see whether indentation lines up, when the line you need to line up with is a long way above. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Missing one closing parentheses here:

```
find_full_word.append((n_term, "PERSON"))
```